# What is the best way to get value by ID in the CF7 input field?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, input, contact-form-7

I have attached an image showing how the value by id appears outside the input div. In CF7 form, I have used the following code.

```html
<div> 
[text* email id:result placeholder "Your Email Address"] 
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Get value where? in Javascript Or php? and what code have you tried so far to get the value?

Comment: I'm getting value from local storage,  following is JS code which i'm using to read value.

<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var getEmail = localStorage.getItem('email')
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("email"); 

});
</script>

And on contact form 7 i'm trying to get value by id, which is as fellow.

     <div> 
            [text* email id:result placeholder "Your Email Address"] 
        </div>

Comment: change `document.getElementById("result").innerHTML` to `document.getElementById("result").value`.

Comment: Thank you Vijay, it's work like magic.